# How to make the screen blink from the command prompt?

Tags: bash, bell, flash

Is there a Linux command that makes the screen blink for a fraction of a second? Possibly on all virtual desktops?

I would use it to get a visual feedback to signal the end of a build, something like:

```
$ make; blink
```

I already tried with the `beep` command, to get an audio feedback, but on my system it produces no sound.

Comment: (1) "Possibly on all virtual desktops" -- You do not mean virtual terminals, you mean GUI desktops, right? What is your desktop environment then? (2) Why the `gnu-screen` tag?

Comment: Possibly [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Linux desktops support notifications; see `notify-send`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, I mean GUI desktops. I am using KDE.

Comment: You can either send a notification to your DE, or use a terminal that supports a "visual" bell.

Comment: GPIO pin driving a solenoid, which shakes a flaky, dollar-store HDMI cable close to the connector!

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) to lower and then raise the brightness of your monitor. These commands are listed on a [linuxhint](https://linuxhint.com/display_brightness_commandline/) query-

```
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

You could set your "blink" to be an alias for lowering the brightness, waiting something like a second, then re-raising it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using KDE, you should check out the built-in Konsole (the terminal emulator) feature that notices when activity stops:

> to monitor changes in a log or any other file, check the View menu and its Monitor for Activity/Silence options. Selecting this will allow Konsole to alert you via desktop notifications when something happens (or stops happening) in the tab for which you enabled the option

> As with any other KDE application, you can choose the type of notifications for Konsole. You'll find the dialog under Settings > Configure Notifications.

See under [Working With Files and
Commands](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-konsole-default-kde-terminal-emulator/)
(a *makeuseof.com* article).
You should be able to choose a "visual bell" as it is in the Konsole [api](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-konsole-default-kde-terminal-emulator/).

Alternatively, if using X11, not Wayland, you can play with the display output:

```
xset dpms force off; sleep 1; xset dpms force on
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your Putty terminal (ex: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306432/27616) (or others terminals) to have this "visual bell" instead of (or in addition to) the regular bell, and trigger it by printing a 'bel' :

```
printf '\07'
```

Comment: I do not have a Putty terminal. I would like to do it from a bash terminal.
The `printf '\07'` command is recognized, but it does nothing.

Comment: A "bash terminal" is a terminal - such as PuTTY - running an instance of `bash`. If you're not using PuTTY you ought to say which terminal application you're using, because it's that which will implement flash instead of a sound when sent the ASCII "BEL" code (`0x07`)

Comment: @roaima - Isn't Bash a terminal application?

Comment: @Pietro `bash` is a shell (application) that can run in a terminal (but doesn't have to). It is responsible for taking your commands, executing them, and returning the results. The terminal (tool) is responsible for the interface between software - often a shell - and you. For example, `bash` interprets `printf '\07'` to mean "_send an ASCII BEL character to the output_". The terminal understands "_if I receive an ASCII BEL character from a program, make a sound_". It's the second part that seems not to be working in your situation